# How do I force all websites / a single domain with a universal command to use HTTPS?

Tags: ssl, nginx

I just installed a new control panel (Vesta) and it has automated SSL support via Let'sEncrypt. Now all my domains have a SSL certificate, but all domains still open with http:// (when using *domain*.com), instead of https://.

**Now I want all domains to start using https:// by default. How do I do that?**

I don't have many domains (~15), so I wouldn't mind a per-domain approach, but a server-wide single script would be better, if possible. If going per-domain, I do would like a universal script (e.g. $domain, instead of literally example.com).

*For the record, I've got a Ubuntu 16.04 VPS running Nginx+php-fpm without Apache.*

<sub>P.s. I saw a bunch of threads regarding this subject, via Google, that didn't help me out, all posted on SO without closing votes.Therefor I've put it here.</sub>

<sub>*Honestly think it's weird it is so hard turning on SSL by default in this era, as it should almost be as standard as food, drinks and a roof above your head..*</sub>

Answer (score -1):

You could create a server block listening on port 80 which HTTP 301 redirects to your HTTPS domain.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  yourdomain.com;
    return       301 https://yourdomain.com$request_uri;
}
```

You could also have one server block than listens on both 80 and 443 but uses HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) to prefer 443.

```
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains";
```

When this header is enabled, the request on port 80 will be 301 redirected to 443. Browsers will remember your domain prefers HTTPS and subsequent requests will redirect to 443 before even requesting 80 traffic. In Chrome this appears as a 307 internal redirect on your network tab.

IMPORTANT: Please note this is different than **preloading** HSTS which is a bit more permanent on the internet.

```
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";
```

I hope that helps.

Cheers,
Ian

Comment: Just for the record, I have to put those pieces of code within a http { } tag within the nginx.conf file, located at /etc/nginx, right? Or am I wrong? And this doesn't include www to non-www redirect, right? Update: Tried that and didn't change a thing..

Comment: Slight update, instead of putting it in the nginx.conf file directly, that file itself includes everything put inside the conf.d folder, so I made a new script called 'https.conf'. I've put your lines in that folder, but nothing is working.

Comment: Our setup must be different. I don't use a conf.d folder. I just use the nginx.conf provided after compiling from source. Sorry it didn't solve your issue. Not sure why the down vote though. Not every response will solve the problem. Down votes discourage people trying to help. Cheers.